# Updating Docproperty field in docx

Tags: python, docx, python-docx

How can I update Docproperty field in docx on python? I've tried python-docx library, but didn't find the solution. Then i used DocxTemplate, exactly .render() function and variables like {{ variable }} inserted in docx file. But after rendering the tempale variables transform to text.
But i need to update { DOCPROPERTY  variable_name * MERGEFORMAT } in docx document and save it as Docproperty field.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: `python-docx` has no API support for fields as of the current release. I'd suggest searching on `python-docx fields` and see what workaround code others may have developed. This is one such result: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58479000/how-to-update-fields-in-ms-word-with-python-docx